# Why doesn't WebStorm provide method documentation on the second level?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, javascript-intellisense

I recently started to use WebStorm and I've noticed that the IDE sometimes doesn't provide property or method documentation on the second level. So, when I call an object and try to explore the available methods and properties on the second level, no documentation or hints are displayed. It only displays "unresolved method".

[image: tagName and getAttribute() without documentation]

I've already tried checking the settings and making sure that I'm using the latest version of WebStorm, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Is there a way to change this behavior in WebStorm or am I missing something?

I have tried to enable "show full method signatures" and that **worked for a minute**.
After that it suddenly stopped and went back to no documentation.
Also i have tried to reset the JavaScript language version to ES 5.1 and then back to ES 6+.

[image: Changing of the language version]

[image: Enable "show full method signatures"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the exact type of `event` parameter is unknown, so the type is inferred as generic `Event`; `EventTarget` interface doesn't have `tagName` and `getAttribute` properties. You need to explicitly tell the IDE the type of the HTMLElement which is your target using type annotations. See https://freshman.tech/snippets/typescript/fix-value-not-exist-eventtarget/

For pure JavaScript, this can be done using JSDoc annotations